WPF DataBinding Error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: viewService in CustomDataGrid
Problem Description:
I am working on a WPF project where I am using a CustomDataGrid inside a UserControl. The CustomDataGrid is bound to a collection in the DataContext. I am encountering the following error when the grid is loaded:
Error:
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: viewService

I have confirmed that the DataContext is set correctly, and my bindings in the grid seem correct. I believe the issue is related to the CustomDataGrid and DataTemplates used in my ResourceDictionary, but I can't seem to pinpoint the cause.
Here’s a simplified version of my UserControl, DataGrid, and DataTemplates:
MRE:
1. XAML (UserControl):
<UserControl x:Class="ExampleApp.Views.BoreholeDeviationSurveysView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp.Views">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExampleApp;component/DataTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="SurveyGrid" 
                  CanUserAddRows="True" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TrajectoryMeasurements}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Measured Depth" Binding="{Binding MD}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="True Vertical Depth" Binding="{Binding TVD}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

2. Resource Dictionary (DataTemplates.xaml):
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp.ViewModels">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeasurementName}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>

3. ViewModel:
public class BoreholeDeviationSurveysViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel> TrajectoryMeasurements { get; set; }

    public BoreholeDeviationSurveysViewModel()
    {
        TrajectoryMeasurements = new ObservableCollection<TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel>
        {
            new TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel { MD = 1000, TVD = 900 },
            new TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel { MD = 1200, TVD = 1100 }
        };
    }
}

public class TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel
{
    public double MD { get; set; }
    public double TVD { get; set; }
    public string MeasurementName => $"MD: {MD}, TVD: {TVD}";
}

What I’ve Tried:

Verified that DataContext is properly set.

Ensured that ItemsSource is bound to a valid collection.

Confirmed the DataTemplates are correctly referenced in the ResourceDictionary.


However, the issue persists, and the error still appears when loading the CustomDataGrid.
Question:
What could be causing the "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: viewService" error in this scenario, and how can I resolve it?

My pure guess would be that during initialization TrajectoryMeasurements is bound, but it's null during initialization, before executing the constructor. Could you try doing public ObservableCollection<TrajectoryMeasurementViewModel> TrajectoryMeasurements { get;  } = new(); ? Note the instantiation with new(). You can preserve set; if you need it, of course.

We cannot reproduce it with your limited code.

Culprit here is the custom data grid, because we can't see it, we can't really help. I have never seen a reason to create a custom data grid anyway, maybe you need to change how you populate it instead?
